# My 4-year-old with-holds poop even though he's on meds. How can I help him?

Tags: pre-schooler, constipation

My son is almost 4 years old and is still holding his poop in. He has been on Miramax for a while now but we were trying to figure out how much to give him and when to give him only due to the fact that it gave him diarrhea at the beginning.

Now he is still holding his poop and he is severely backed up that caused him to throw up. Also he doesn't want to eat nothing but chips and other junk food. We are trying a teaspoon a day sometimes twice a day. The biggest thing is that he is constantly crying due to the fact that he needs to poop but doesn't want to.

Another thing is when we try to start potty training he doesn't tell us that he needs to go to the potty and he doesn't mind having a wet pull-up and only pulls at his pull-up after he does poop a little bit.

Please help. I'm afraid that he won't be able to go to kindergarten in a couple of years due to the fact that he will not go to the potty like a big boy.

**Update**
My husband decided yesterday when he got home from work to leave off my son's pull-up until bedtime. I didn't think that it would work and there would be pee and poop everywhere but it did work. By bedtime he had pooped 4 times in his training toilet that you can buy from Walmart. We are still giving him his medicine but we are going in the right direction. Yay.

Comment: Can you add a few more details by answering some or all of the following questions: What does his pediatrician say - about the withholding, the throwing up and also about the diet? What methods (rewards/punishment) have you tried so far to encourage pooping and how did they work? How long has this been going on for? Has he ever had a bad experience with a toilet that would leave him scared to use it?

Comment: His pediatrician prescribed him the medicine for him and to try to get him to drink some more water which he doesn't like to drink. Normally if he had potty in the big boy potty he would get a sticker. This has been going on for about 6 months to a year now. As far as a bad experience I don't think so.

Comment: Do the pull ups "lock away" the pee (ie can you pee in them and still be comfortable)? If so, there’s every incentive to pee away but hold in the poo (which is smelly and uncomfortable). As far as I can tell, any liquid is ok, but water is best because of low sugar content.

Answer (score 1):

I have had exactly the same problem with my now three-year old. He would not make a poo at all, holding it on days (sometimes four or five) at a time. He complained about aching stomach and was crying a lot. We found suppositories the best way to go with him, as various medicines would not work for him. Also, we have changed the diet: lots of home-made soups, the fatter the better. No sweets, no snacks. And absolutely NO chocolate, under any shape or form. He was very upset to begin with (understandably), but after about a week he started pooping - every 2-3 days to begin with.
He poops every day now, but still happens not to poop for a two or three days in a row every now and again.

Comment: He doesn't eat a lot of chocolate but he does love his chips. The biggest thing with him is to get him to drink more water

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that as my son has always been drinking a lot of water, but yes, lot of water. Also, chocolate will make him more constipated. You may want to find some new fancy mugs to get him drinking - new shapes, new colours, etc. My boy also loves drinking through straws, so that maybe something for you to try. In addition, you can try to add some sirup to water, so it'll get his favourite taste.

Comment: I bought some flavor packages that you can add to water to give it flavor and is good for you at the same time

Comment: Great! Now you need to find a right mug/bottle/glass that will make him excited to drink from :D (My boy is usually taking a sip or two from a 'boring' glass, but will drink a half of what's inside his favourite mug with his favourite straw within seconds :D)

Comment: Normally the cup isn't the problem its usually the flavor